# C++ multi-file compilation process

Tags: c++, compilation

i'm trying to minimize header inclusion in a project, maximizing the usage of forward declarations and need to get clear on how exactly the process of C++ compilation works.

It starts of with main.cpp where we allocate object A, therefore we include A.h. Class A uses classes B and C, so i include B.h and C.h. Now if I wanted to allocate B in main.cpp, the compilation would fail.

I can easily include B.h in main.cpp, but I'm wondering if its really necessary, because I'm already including A.h and in A.h I'm including B.h. I read some previous discussions on this topic, where there was something about recursion and recompilation of the source file. So how does that exactly work?

Thanks for any advice. :)

Comment: Indirect inclusion *is* inclusion. When you include a header, the compiler acts as if each line of the header were part of the file. When you include a header in a header, it's as if you copy/pasted each line of that inner header into the outer one and thus into every file that includes it. If the compilation fails in the circumstances you are describing, one of the headers is broken. (Can you create a short, complete, compilable example of the breakage?)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: Yes and no, preprocessors are designed to detect header guards (and `#pragma once` declarations) and avoid even opening the header file for the second time. So yes, theoretically you are *including* the file again, but in practice the cost can be optimized away.

Comment: @David Schwartz: Hmm, now it seems that i just needed to recompile the code, there was some partial compilation thing going on. The reason i started to dig into this is that, i was resolving cross-including between 2 classes and a friend told me, that he uses a trick, that he includes one header file, in this included header file he just uses forward declarations and includes the previous class header in the cpp file. So I got confused where does the cpp file come in.

Answer (score 1):

As a simple rule of thumb, you need to define symbols any time their alignment, interface, or size is required.  If a header only refers to a type as a pointer, you only need to declare it.

All compilation units which reference a header have to go through the paces of understanding it independently.  That is why code in a header increases compile times super-linearly.

You can see exactly what the preprocessor prepares for the compiler if you are interested.  GCC has the below syntax.

```
g++ -E main.cpp
```

MSVC has similar functionality, though I cannot quote it.

> I can easily include B.h in main.cpp, but I'm wondering if its really
>   necessary, because I'm already including A.h and in A.h I'm including
>   B.h

This is a matter of circumstance, I suppose.  The major annoyance with omitting headers, is that usually what happens is someone else changes something in a disparate part of the code base and you have to guess at why you are missing symbols when you update from source control.  Essentially you create dependencies between headers that are not clear at all.

If my whims were law, you could throw an include to any header in an empty cpp file and it would just compile.  I don't see why you wouldn't want that, though I'm not prepared to defend it as the right thing to do in all situations.

Comment: "*you need to define symbols any time their alignment or interface is required*" Or size.

Comment: size is probably the relevant bit of all of it, ty ;)